# Solr indexing wrong language version

Tags: solr, indexing, multilingual

This is my Query:

> ?q=((_keypath_t_pt:("/sitecore/content/Country/Home Page/COMPANY Magazines") AND _language:(pt-BR)) AND _latestversion:(True))&start=0&rows=1000000&fl=*,score&fq=(_language:(pt*))&fq=_indexname:(list_item_search_index_master)&wt=xml

This is one item of the result:

[image: This is one item of the result:]

So I have 2 language versions in sitecore.(pt-BR and en) I edited the title field of the english version to "Magazine 24rds coyote en" and the pt-BR version to "Magazine 24rds coyote pt" so i am able to see which version is indexed and in the result. I have also rebuilt the index after changing this.
So you see the problem. The query shows the items in the right language but the fields are indexed with the false language.

Comment: Do you have a second field inside that document called "_itemcontent_t_pt"? Is it a custom index field? or standard Sitecore field? Is it shared field or versioned?

Comment: Can you also check if you have language fallback set on pt-BR?

Comment: Yes there is a second field called "_itemcontent_t_pt" and the value there is also "Magazine 24rds coyote en". It is a standard sitecore field. And i removed the shared option so i was able to put different values into the different language versions. After setting it to not shared i have rebuilt the index. The language fallback is set on pt-BR so it falls back to en but i think this is not happening in this case because there are values in both languages.

Comment: Try adding a new field instead of changing the type of the field. There are know issues when you change field type from shared to versioned.

Comment: But i think that's not a good idea to add a new field only for a new language? There are more than 5 fields only for this item. Or do i understand something wrong here?

Comment: I mean that changing field from Shared to Versioned may cause issues. Try removing old field which was changed from Shared to Versioned and create a completely new one - just single versioned field.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!